# Automatically log error and terminate application with SmartAssembly

Tags: obfuscation, error-reporting, redgate, smartassembly

I'm using [SmartAssembly](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/) for both general code obfuscation as well as error reporting in an application.

If my application encounters an unhandled exception, I'd like the exception to be logged and then terminate the application without any user interaction. Is it possible to create a SmartAssembly project that allows this?

I've tried setting up the project in the SmartAssembly GUI, as well as on [the command-line](http://www.red-gate.com/SupportCenter/content/SmartAssembly/help/6.7/SA_UsingTheCommandLine) with no luck. Below is the command and arguments I've tried, but so far I can't determine how to get it to both terminate the app and log the error with no user input.

**Create SA Project:**

```
"C:\Program Files\Red Gate\SmartAssembly 6\SmartAssembly.com" 
/create shell.saproj  input=C:\Repositories\MyApp\src\shell.exe 
/output=shell.exe 
/reportappname="MyTestApp" 
/errorreportingtemplate=standard;continueonerror=false,email:"my@email.com"
/reportprojectname="Shell" 
/reportcompanyname="My Company"
```

**Build the project:**

```
"C:\Program Files\Red Gate\SmartAssembly 6\SmartAssembly.com" /build shell.saproj
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SmartAssembly includes a few examples of custom ErrorReportingTemplates, 
located in `Red Gate/SmartAssembly 6/SDK/Exception Reporting/`

The examples are lumped into a few categories:

`Without UI`
`Standard`
`Custom UI`
`Via Email`
`Secured Proxy`
`Silverlight`
`Silverlight Basic`

In each of these folders, there is a .csproj file that one can extend to get their desired results.
Inside the `Without UI` folder is the project we're after, titled `Sample 01 - Without User Interface.csproj`

If you're just after a `.dll` to use and don't care about a re-usable solution, edit this file directly and use the resulting `.dll` file (the alternative being to create a new project, and pull in the reference to `SmartAssembly.SmartExceptionsCore`).

Edit the `OnReportException` function to look like the following:

```
protected override void OnReportException(ReportExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            if (e.SendReport()) break;
        }
        e.TryToContinue = false;
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        proc.Kill();
    }
```

[Here's a Gist of the final result](https://gist.github.com/jdhurst/0872e8f339a132853c6d), if you're confused.

Create the project file with the GUI or via cmd:

```
"C:\Program Files\Red Gate\SmartAssembly 6\SmartAssembly.com" 
/create shell.saproj  input=C:\Repositories\MyApp\src\shell.exe 
/output=shell.exe 
/reportappname="MyTestApp" 
/errorreportingtemplate=MySmartAssemblyLogger.dll;continueonerror=false,email:"my@email.com"
/reportprojectname="Shell" 
/reportcompanyname="My Company"
```

Build with the GUI or via cmd:

```
"C:\Program Files\Red Gate\SmartAssembly 6\SmartAssembly.com" /build shell.saproj
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the example on the website http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/Content/SmartAssembly/help/6.7/SA_UsingTheCommandLine

You should replace "standard" with "auto" and that is supposed to send the error report without the user dialog appearing.

Comment: Using `auto` automatically logged errors, but I couldn't find the right setting to additionally terminate the application without user interaction.